# Why Cython uses gcc optimizations?

Tags: cython, distutils

Cython, by default, calls `gcc` compiler with `-O2` flag, what is the reason behind that, since `-O0` (which reduces compilation time) is the default in `gcc`?

When I run my project with `-O0`, compilation time is reduced by 50%! So I wonder whether there is a strong reason to not use the default.

Comment: I think this is really a `distutils` or `setuptools` question. I think the flags come from there, and that this isn't a decision that Cython makes

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidW noted, this isn't really a Cython issue - but at the same time, it's probably a good default.

If you're reaching for Cython, you very likely care about runtime performance - higher optimization levels in gcc (generally) result in less and faster running code, at the cost of compile time.